# Mysql: how to get a timesliced query with cumulative sum (unexpected result)

Tags: mysql, join, cumulative-sum

I have an RFID access control system. Starting from this table I would like to get a query that allows me to get a graph of the day's attendance time-sliced into 10 min.

The structure of the table is the following:

- `id`
- `id_rfid`
- ...
- `type` (0 = in or 1 = out)
- `success` (0 = yes or 1 = no)
- ...
- `created_at` (timestamp)

I tried (in my test environment with MySQL 5.7) with this query but get me unexpected results. What is wrong?

```
SELECT
    *, 
    SUM(`i`.`conteggio`) AS `cumulativo`
    -- FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(`i`.`created_at`/(10 * 60))*(10 * 60)) AS datetime
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            `id`, 
            `id_rfid`, 
            CASE
                WHEN `type` = 0 AND `success` = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN `type` = 1 AND `success` = 0 THEN -1
                ELSE 0
            END AS `conteggio`, 
            `created_at`, 
            FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`) AS `created_datetime`
        FROM 
            `tbl_ingresso` 
        LIMIT 100
    ) AS i
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            `id`, 
            `id_rfid`, 
            CASE
                WHEN `type` = 0 AND `success` = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN `type` = 1 AND `success` = 0 THEN -1
                ELSE 0
            END AS `conteggio`, 
            `created_at`, 
            FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`) AS `created_datetime`
        FROM 
            `tbl_ingresso` 
        LIMIT 100
    ) AS j
ON 
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`i`.`created_at`)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`j`.`created_at`)) AND
    `i`.`created_at` >= `j`.`created_at`
GROUP BY 
    1,4
    -- CEIL(`i`.`created_at`/(10 * 60)) 
-- LIMIT 100
;
```

RESULT:

```
id  id_rfid conteggio   created_at  created_datetime    ... cumulativo  
2   1       1           1479110294  2016-11-14 08:58:14     1   
3   92      1           1479111188  2016-11-14 09:13:08     2   
4   40      1           1479111220  2016-11-14 09:13:40     3   
5   101     1           1479111227  2016-11-14 09:13:47     4   
6   100     1           1479112470  2016-11-14 09:34:30     5   
7   100     1           1479112483  2016-11-14 09:34:43     6   
8   74      1           1479113518  2016-11-14 09:51:58     7   
9   128     1           1479113608  2016-11-14 09:53:28     8   
10  117     1           1479113671  2016-11-14 09:54:31     9   
11  55      1           1479113866  2016-11-14 09:57:46     10  
12  40      -1          1479114971  2016-11-14 10:16:11     -11 (expected result: 9)
13  92      -1          1479114980  2016-11-14 10:16:20     -12 (expected result: 8)
14  125     1           1479115206  2016-11-14 10:20:06     13  (expected result: 9)
15  126     1           1479115212  2016-11-14 10:20:12     14  (expected result: 10)
16  33      1           1479115218  2016-11-14 10:20:18     15  ...
17  101     -1          1479116013  2016-11-14 10:33:33     -16 
18  128     -1          1479117003  2016-11-14 10:50:03     -17 
19  117     -1          1479117324  2016-11-14 10:55:24     -18 
20  128     1           1479117548  2016-11-14 10:59:08     19  
21  1       -1          1479117669  2016-11-14 11:01:09     -20 
22  131     1           1479117952  2016-11-14 11:05:52     21  
23  129     1           1479118134  2016-11-14 11:08:54     22  
24  1       1           1479119066  2016-11-14 11:24:26     23  
25  126     -1          1479119237  2016-11-14 11:27:17     -24 
26  125     -1          1479119244  2016-11-14 11:27:24     -25
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to @muhamed for the right answer. First step is ok. Now i need to time-slice it to get this result:

```
cumulativo  datetime    
1           2016-11-14 09:00:00 
4           2016-11-14 09:20:00 
6           2016-11-14 09:40:00 
10          2016-11-14 10:00:00 
8           2016-11-14 10:20:00 
11          2016-11-14 10:30:00 
10          2016-11-14 10:40:00 
9           2016-11-14 11:00:00 
10          2016-11-14 11:10:00 
...
```

Comment: You have (probably a lot) of columns in the `SELECT` list, that aren't included in the `GROUP BY` list nor passed to an aggregation function. That may give funny results and is in fact considered an error in almost all DBMS and in MySQL with stricter settings. You should first fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the aggregate function on `j.conteggio` as following:

```
SUM(`j`.`conteggio`) AS `cumulativo`
```